# CS2 Raw files not opening, need help

Tags: nikon, raw

low tech old guy operating in a high tech world.  I have CS2 and can't open raw files, I have downloaded the latest version of the DNG converter, but I can't get my CS2 program to recognize it.  Can someone please walk me through what must be done?  I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you talking about Photoshop CS2? Also what's your camera as raw format may not be supported by CS2.

Answer (score 1):

The newest (free) [updates for Creative Suite](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/legacy-version-updates.html) will update your software. CS2 through 6 are at the bottom of the webpage.

The Adobe DNG Converter you are using should match what is the [newest available](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html) on their website.

You'll also want to check if you have Microsoft's Camera Codec Pack (assuming you are using Windows), instructions for installation on newer versions of Windows are [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/microsoft-camera-codec-pack-for-windows-10-64-bit/00a1ae0a-936e-42fd-b928-ca38eb2fd8f6?page=3&auth=1).

With updated software your RAW files should open without any problems.

Comment: I can confirm this (re the end-of-life CS2 update).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple applications to open raw files. You can then convert the images into 16bit Tiff files and edit them in your version of photoshop.

Canon has its own raw processing software called [Digital Photo Professional](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/software/digital-photo-professional.aspx?os=LINUX&language=EN)
I presume other manufacturers have their own version to do the same.

You can also convert Raw files with [DCRAW](http://www.centrostudiprogressofotografico.it/en/dcraw/) (It's a command line tool).

If you find typing commands too daunting you can use a frontend like http://www.wizards.de/rawdrop/

Else try converting using [Rawtherapee](http://rawtherapee.com) or [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe CS2 should come with Adobe Camera Raw, Open Adobe Bridge, then you can select a file and use the file menu to choose " open in Photoshop " or  " open in camera raw " because as you know CS2 will not open the RAW file. which ever one you choose it will open it in Camera Raw then you will have a button at the bottom to "open" the file and it will open in CS2. You can then make changes and save them but it will save them as a PSD file ( or the file you choose )

I do most of my editing with camera raw and rarely open them in Photoshop. The beauty of Bridge and Camera Raw is that You can choose to save your edits as a JPG or a TIFF file or close the file and it will save the edits as nondestructive, (if you have it set up in the preferences ) it will save the edits in a sidecar file and only apply the edits when you open the file in bridge but will not change the original RAW file. It will only apply edits to any conversions you make I.E. "save file as"

If you want to use DNG converter then you need to open DNG CONVERTER and then select the file you want to convert to a DNG file and convert it. Then you can open the DNG file in CS2.

Here is PDF from adobe

[Understanding 
Adobe Camera Raw 3](https://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/phscs2ip_camraw3.pdf)

and a breif explanation of what i wrote above.

[How to Use Adobe Camera Raw With CS2](https://itstillworks.com/use-adobe-camera-raw-cs2-7426.html)